# Why does CrunchBase say StackOverflow serves 26 million users?

Tags: discussion, users

In https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/stack-exchange, it says:

> Stack Overflow alone serving more than 26 million professional and
>   novice programmers each month

This appears to be a somewhat perplexing statement. How does that correlate with the amount of registered users, and more so with the actual number of worldwide programmers/developers?

e.g. see http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/01/IDC-software-developers.

Comment: Good question. Probably only CrunchBase knows the answer?

Comment: I would guess it's *their* estimate of the number of visitors per month.

Comment: Which still doesn't entirely make sense, and raises questions about how this has been counted. To Oded - they typically got that number from someone they trusted, I assume, or would like to...

Comment: @matt - did you look at the team section? Compare that to the [team page](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) we maintain (which is not hidden and they could easily use as a basis of theirs). Then tell me - why do you trust their figures?

Comment: @PatrickHofman the numbers are actually even slightly more perplexing if they are old

Comment: Related: https://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc (quantcast statistics for the network)

Comment: @Oded oh god, the hovering makes you all move.  ... well, not all, but too many

Comment: Except for Oded @Won't. He moves us .... *wipes away tear*

Comment: Any idea how quantcast get their numbers, do they sit on the Internet backbone or something?

Comment: @matt Here is [Quantcast FAQ](https://www.quantcast.com/help-center/faqs/) page. It's a combination of many things like ISP backbone, tracking code, toolbar providers... etc. If you do a 'View Page Source' you will see Quantcast tracking code with 'quant.js'

Answer (score 7):

I am a regular visitor of [CrunchBase](https://www.crunchbase.com/) site. It's one of the leading website as for the start-up companies funding round news goes. Their data is more accurate on the funding part. Rest of the data such as company description, team members, site stats, etc. is gathered (and added/updated by its staff members, official company employees, site visitors, etc.) from the various sources apart from official about Stack Exchange page. This data over the time does gets *outdated* and I have noticed the same with few other start-up companies.

But, as per the below excerpt ([source: Content Guidelines](https://info.crunchbase.com/docs/guidelines/)) *anyone* can edit CrunchBase data: (emphasis mine)

> CrunchBase is the free database of technology companies, people, and
> investors that **anyone can edit**.  Our mission is to make information
> about the startup world available to everyone and maintainable by
> anyone.  These guidelines explain our criteria for accepting and
> moderating content.
>
> Above all, we want our dataset to be accurate.  If you ever find information that is inaccurate, incomplete, or misleading, please correct it.  Remember, **anyone can edit** CrunchBase

Each profile on CrunchBase site including [SE's profile](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/stack-exchange) page has an '**UPDATE**' button on the top-right in each section for updating the existing info. There is also an '**ADD**' button (top-nav) for adding new information.

As for Stack Overflow's '**26 million**' users goes, there are many sources that can be found by a simple Google search for "[stack overflow 26 million](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stack%20overflow%2026%20million)". The 26 million represents number of 'unique visitors'. The SE's About page says: (emphasis mine)

> Since then, the Stack Exchange network has grown into a top-50 online
> destination, with Stack Overflow alone **serving** more than 26
> million professional and novice programmers every month.

Notice 'Serving' and it should not be treated as 'number of *registered* users'. SE currently uses 3 analytics companies (for more details see [Joel Spoksy's answer)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263619/are-some-se-web-tracking-beacons-more-important-than-others/263625#263625) for measuring the traffic, keywords, etc. metrics. One of them is Quantcast and you can find the details of at [Quantcast analysis](https://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc) (link given in the comment by Oded). Please note that Quantcast, ComScore (or any other 3rd party analytics company for that matter) will *not* give the 'number of *registered* users' stats as they don't have access to that *private* data. Some research companies reports / case studies mentions about the '*registered* users' numbers but then they usually will give you the source (read next para) of that information.

The Stack Exchange's official [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) listing page ('visits' shown are 'per day') gives the better stats of many things. I'm not sure on how often this listing page gets updated. One of the column on the listing page also displays the '**number of users**' (tooltip shows "*number* **registered** and **unregistered** users") for each of the SE's Network sites. There is a big difference between 'number of visitors' and 'number of *registered* users'. I would also recommend reading the official '[About SE](https://stackexchange.com/about)' page especially the '2014 Stack Exchange Network Statistics' section. As per the stats given there, it says there are **3.8M Registered Stack Overflow users** as of year 2014.

**P.S.**

As per the "[All Contributors for Stack Exchange](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/stack-exchange/contributors)" profile, you will see some of the Stack Exchange team members name such as Will Cole, Courtny Cotten, Erin Gray, etc. who have made contributions (see # in the contributions column) to it.

Comment: Great comprehensive answer. 

Well, it appears that by [narrowing down to only the StackOverflow TLD on quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?country=US), and picking the monthly display there, the numbers are close to an order of magnitude smaller (~7.5M, looking at the `people` metric there, which appears to be the most relevant one). Whereas the numbers for the entire network are close to the communicated number of 26M. I don't want to say someone took the number and gave a different sentence around it, but it may appear as if quantcast is in stark disagreement.

Comment: So it is rather very awkwardly difficult to support that number with the data that is publicly available, it may seem, or does it?

Comment: @matt If I were to trust the numbers then I will have to go by the number given by Stack Exchange as they have the logs of traffic and the users registration. Quantcast or Alexa use different sources (internt backbone providers and other data) to display the results. But, at least we have some metric to compare.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I am not sure what you mean... the number 26M provided by Stack Exchange on the about page, isn't even supported by their public data query api/page, nor the numbers on http://stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: @matt As for 26M goes on about page, I don't know when was the last time it got updated. I am not sure how often the stats under "All Sites" get updated either. Also, remember page visits/traffic goes up and down. It differs month to month. Only SE team can tell.

Comment: It's somewhere between impossible to extremely improbable that there were 26 million users, and now there's just 5, or 7. Regardless of the pace of updating....

Comment: @matt no no ... it's other way... lot of time its kinda confusing when they (reporters) say "a website has 26 millions users visiting to their site" what they mean to say is "a website has 26 millions VISITORS visiting to their site"... as for the "registered users" goes the 5M approximate is correct.

Comment: Dude, it's not reporters, it is what Stack Exchange put on their about page ;)

Comment: @matt I understand that and I was talking in general.

Comment: @matt I noticed your 1st comment about "narrowing down to only the StackOverflow TLD on" link has 'country=US'. Why are you restricting to US Only? Stack Overflow serves to many visitors (and registered users) around the world. Here is what it looks like for [SO GLOBAL](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?country=GLOBAL) - make sure to pick monthly display.

Comment: Gee thanks, no idea why the default display was for only the U.S.... the numbers are of course, very different now, and closer to the StackExchange claim. Do you work for StackExchange or something? :)

Comment: @matt It does default to US because for most of the companies US traffic is the key metric. Glad to see that the numbers are close/better than what it's been quoted out there. No, I don't work for SE but it's a great company to work for.

Answer (score 2):

I guess they picked that number from the [about](https://stackexchange.com/about) (that is a rather good copy/pasting what they did):

> Since then, the Stack Exchange network has grown into a top-50 online destination, with Stack Overflow alone serving more than 26 million professional and novice programmers every month.

*How does that correlate with the amount of registered users?*

It doesn't. It is just the number of unique visitors on Stack Overflow I guess. The total number of users is somewhat about 5 million (I just took the currently highest user ID as a basis for this, it doesn't take deleted users into account).