# Why does Stack Overflow use two trackers unlike other Stack Exchange sites and for what purposes?

Tags: support, privacy

I recently installed a browser extension to detect trackers on a webpage.

According to that extension, Stack Overflow uses two trackers:

1. Comscore Beacon
2. Quantserve Tracker

While other Stack Exchange sites (I have checked MSE, History, SFF, Arqade and Politics) use just Comscore Beacon.

Why does Stack Overflow need two trackers? What kind of browsing activities do they track on SE sites?

Comment: For Jobs maybe?

Comment: @PatrickHofman That seems logical given that only SO has the jobs module so it makes sense that all others have just one tracker. So one tracker for main SO and one for jobs? What kind of data do they track?

Comment: Don't know. Just a hunch it was Jobs.

Comment: I just checked, and all the sites you mention do have the Quantcast code in them, not sure why you're not seeing them. As to your "why" question, Joel (our CEO) has elaborated about that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263619/are-some-se-web-tracking-beacons-more-important-than-others/263625#263625

Comment: @balpha Thanks that's very helpful. If the official response will be the same then I guess we could close it as dupe? Or can we expect further information as to what kind of browsing behaviors are recorded and used by SE other than where the traffic is coming from?

Comment: I don't think we use Comscore and QuantCast for anything other than as a thing we can point people to as a source of traffic numbers. They're not really useful for more fine-grained analytics. For that (stuff like A/B tests etc.) we use a home-grown tool ([PRIZM](https://twitter.com/kav2k/status/826868385766060032)) and sometimes Google Analytics. And there's [Providence](https://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/). Anyway, yeah it's probably a dupe as it stands, but feel free to open a new question if you're looking for something more detailed.